# Animating a div with CSS on hover

Tags: animation, css, keyframe

I'm trying to animate a div on hover using CSS3's @keyframes rule. The code for the animation is at the very bottom of [this page](http://www.theapplenewsreel.com/style.css) (right after the generously marked "HERE BE ANIMATION" comment ASCII art). That includes the @keyframes rule, the div, and the div:hover. The page where I wanted this animation is [right here](http://www.theapplenewsreel.com/MacHQ). For some reason, the animation doesn't work; this is the first time I've tried using CSS animation, so there's probably some novice mistake somewhere.

Comment: The @keyframes rule is not supported in any browsers.

Firefox supports an alternative, the @-moz-keyframes rule.

Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the @-webkit-keyframes rule. Are you sure you still need to mess with this? =)

Comment: I think the @-webkit-keyframes rule is already in there; I abstained from the -moz because Dreamweaver didn't recognize it as a valid @keyframes variant. But I tested the page in Chrome, and the animation doesn't display.

Comment: I think you left a link out of your question that points to the actual page that you're interested in

Comment: My bad. The link to the stylesheet now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to animate your div from 0px to 200px, it's much more easier to use jQuery solution.
jQuery offers cross-browser compatibility compare to @keyframe, which is only supported in Safari and Chrome.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgcxL/

EDIT:

If you don't want your users to be limited only to Chrome and Safari, you should definitely consider jQuery. It's very simple to use. Just add this code somewhere between your `<head></head>` tags.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.macanimation').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({top: '200px'});
    });
  });
</script>
```

EDIT 2:

I forgot document.ready(). Re-paste the code above.
Also add position: absolute; to your div and  add 'px' to your width:

```
div.macanimation {
    position: absolute;
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right:40px;
    margin:auto;
    background-image:url(/Photos/MacHQ.png);
}
```

Tested, working.

Comment: I'd love to, but I know much less about jQuery than I do about CSS3 (as in, I've never once used it). I'll try it if it's the only possible solution; otherwise, I'd prefer to stick to CSS3.

Comment: Actually, I've just put the latest jquery.js into my root/js folder, and I'm ready to take the jQuery plunge. Where do I place this script?
$('div').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({top: '200px'});
});

Comment: Alright, I've added the code to the page (and pointed the script to a local version of the jquery.mins.js file). So far, nothing.

Comment: This seems to work. For the moment, I've created a Hype animation (of which I'm not a huge fan, since the application generates huge, incomprehensible amounts of code which I can't troubleshoot or customize). But I'm going to use this kind of animation a couple more times across my site, and I'll use jQuery from now on. Thanks!

Comment: I wont use Dreamweaver cause it adds a lot of extra unneeded coding. Best way to go is TextPad/Notepad. All documentation is provided free on jquery.com

Comment: As much as I love the plaintext approach, I prefer Dreamweaver's split mode, where I can code and the changes appear live in a preview of the actual page.